# Problem PUTNAM of the day - Harvard Mathematics department

Tags: contest-math

Let $f$ be a twice-differentiable real-valued function satisfying $f(x)+f''(x)= -xg(x)f'(x)$, where $g(x) \geq 0$ for all real $x$. Prove that $|f(x)|$ is bound.

Honnestly I worked on this problem for a good while and I just don't know how to solve it.

Is anyone could give me the principal details how to solve it (hints)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$. Observe that $h(x)$ is a non-negative function. On the other hand, we see that
$$
h'(x)=2f'(x)\left[f(x)+f''(x)\right]=-2xg(x)\ f'(x)^2.
$$
Thus $h'(x)\leq 0$ when $x\geq 0$ and $h'(x)\geq 0$ when $x\leq 0$. Hence $h(x)$ attains its maximum at $x=0$. Since $|f(x)|$ is bounded by $\sqrt{h(x)}\leq \sqrt{h(0)}$, it follows that $f(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: (Note that this is modeled on the common proof that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ starting from the differential-equation definition of the functions.)

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's how I figured it out...

Comment: What proof starting from the differential equation definition are you referring to?  Could you post a link.  Thanks